# Apache Virtual Hosts - Map different paths of the same domain (or IP) to different sites

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, apache2

I'm running Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu).
I have only one domain name.
I would like to map different sites to different paths after the domain name.

For example:

`mydomain.com/test001` maps to `/var/www/test001/public`
`mydomain.com/test002` maps to `/var/www/test002/public`

I've already tried many different virtual host configurations but none of them worked.
Could anyone please tell me the right syntax of the virtual host?

**EDIT** 
I've changed my configuration according to the answer given by @JoeSlav,
now this is my virtual host conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test06.com
    ServerAlias www.test06.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test06/public

    Alias /test03/ /var/www/test03/public
    Alias /test04/ /var/www/test04/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I ask for http://test06.com/test03/ I get the directory listing page. I can see my index page in the list but if try to click on it (or if write the complete path on the browser) I get this message:
**"Not Found"**
**"The requested URL /test03/index.html was not found on this server"**

Some additional information:
 - `/var/www/test06/public/index.html` is correctly shown by the browser if I ask for test06.com;
 - I'm mapping test06.com to my server ip through the hosts file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by JoeSlav was almost correct.
There has to be no trailing slash after the sub-path parameter.

This is the working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test06.com
    ServerAlias www.test06.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test06/public

    Alias /test03 /var/www/test03/public
    Alias /test04 /var/www/test04/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple virtual hosts, just different Aliases:

```
Alias /test001/ /var/www/test001/public
Alias /test002/ /var/www/test002/public
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work, probably I didn't do exactly what you're suggesting.
I updated my question with the virtual host configuration and details about what is not working.
Thanks a lot.